# iOS Chome browser - download file link

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, google-chrome, browserstack

Suppose I have controller which returns file (docx for example, but format doesn't matter, same behavior with jpg, png, etc)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var fileName = "File.docx";
        var filePath = @$"C:\Sources\{fileName}";

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
    }
}
```

If I use iOS Safari I get download dialog:
[image]

But in case of iOS Chrome, it opens content of the file and places it on the webpage:
[image]

In case of Chrome on Android tables, it works correctly:
[image]

Is it possible to fix this behavior for iOS Chrome somehow?

To understand the context of the problem: I place such a link on some web page. And when user clicks on it, iOS Chrome replaces this page with content of a file instead of downloading this file.

**PS** Btw, when I try the same but using some unknown binary file, iOS Chrome starts to work correctly:

[image]

Comment: I think there is something wrong with you content type. For .dox files you should use "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Comment: @habib Just have tried with same result. I don't think this is a reason. I also tried jpeg with correct content type, with same result.

Comment: yes, then it may be browser-specific behaviour. I will try it myself also.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but your `contentType` is not looking right to me.

Please try with `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var fileName = "File.docx";
        var filePath = @$"C:\Sources\{fileName}";

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", fileName);
    }
}
```

For more information about contentType please read [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc).

Comment: it hasn't solved the problem. :-(

Comment: Actually your fix has change nothing for all types of browsers and devices I tried before. So I think this isn't a cause.

Comment: Yes that's right